# Wait for all the results of a CompletableFuture and act on those values?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I'm looking for the best way, in Java, to asynchronously run some tasks calculating some values and when they're all gathered, run some further calculation on them.

I thought I was going down the right path with this

```
    var f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Service.findPlayers(filter, maxCount, LeaderboardType.Unranked));
    var f2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Service.findPlayers(filter, maxCount, LeaderboardType._1x1_RM));
    var f3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Service.findPlayers(filter, maxCount, LeaderboardType.TG_RM));

    var x = CompletableFuture.allOf(f1, f2, f3);
```

until I realized that unfortunately `allOf()` doesn't return a list with the results of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` but `void` instead? Is there any alternative? Otherwise I'd have to store the results in some sort of "global variable" and then access them from the `when()` call, which completely defeats the whole purpose of using `supplyAync` vs `runAsync`, I guess.

Comment: The method `CompletableFuture.allOf()` is not a `void` method ... it returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`!

Answer (score 0):

You do `CompletableFuture::allOf`, just like you do it now, but also `join` it :

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(f1, f2, f3).join();
```

and then you do:

```
Stream.of(f1, f2, f3)
      .map(CompletableFuture::join)
      .....
```

There is no joining in the above operation, though, as the features are already completed.

**EDIT**

If you do not want to block:

```
 var f1 = ...
 var f2 = ...
 var f3 = ...

 CompletableFuture.allOf(f1, f2, f3)
                  .thenAccept(x -> {
                       f1.join();
                       f2.join();
                       f3.join();
                   })
```

Comment: There _is_ joining because the `allOf` method does not join. That means the tasks could still be running (asynchronously). Alternatively, you could `join` on the returned `CompletableFuture` of the `allOf` method, first.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose my bad, I missed to mention the _first_ `join` after `allOf`.

Comment: Won't that first join() call block my current thread?

Comment: @devouredelysium yes it will, see edit. Is that what you are looking for?